# Changing the application icon like in Telegram

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I need to programmatically implement changing the application icon, like in the Telegram application. I searched for an answer on Google, but didn't find anything like it. In the Telegram application, in the application settings, you can replace the default application icon with one of the proposed ones, and after restarting the application, the icon changes.

S
e
a
r
c
h in Gooogle

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy Steps to dynamically change Launcher App Icon

> Step 1:- Create empty classes for declaring icons which you want to
> use in App Launcher Icon(if you have n number of icon then you have to
> create n number of Empty classes), For Example , I used 2 icons so i
> created 2 classes one for new Launcher Icon and another for old icon.
> For new icon i created an class NewIconAlias and for old Icon
> OldIconAlias.

NewLauncherAlias.kt

```
class NewLauncherAlias {
}
```

OldLauncherAlias.kt

```
class OldLauncherAlias {
}
```

> Step 2:- Declare `<activity-alias>` in manifest.
> Note:- We have to declare all icons in manifest which we want to use for changing dynamically launcher icon.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DynamicLauncherIcon"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity-alias
        android:name="com.demo.dynamiclaunchericon.alias.OldLauncherAlias"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="Old Icon"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name="com.demo.dynamiclaunchericon.alias.NewLauncherAlias"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_new"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_new_round"
        android:label="New Icon"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
</application>
```

we have 2 icons only so we declare 2 .

> Step 3:- Now we have to perform change launcher icon request from Activity/Fragment .
> For Changing Launcher icon, we have to first Disable old or existing launcher icon then Enable new icon which we declare in manifest.

Disabling Old/Existing Icon :-

```
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        ComponentName(
            this@MainActivity,
            OldLauncherAlias::class.java,
        ),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP,
    )
```

Enabling New Icon :-

```
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        ComponentName(
            this@MainActivity,
            NewLauncherAlias::class.java,
        ),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP,
    )
```

Activity code to update Launcher Icon :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val mBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
    setContentView(mBinding.root)
    mBinding.changeIcon.setOnClickListener {
        updateToNewIcon(this)
    }

    mBinding.oldIcon.setOnClickListener {
        updateToOldIcon(this)
    }
}

private fun updateToOldIcon(MainActivity: MainActivity) {
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        ComponentName(
            this@MainActivity,
            OldLauncherAlias::class.java,
        ),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP,
    )
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        ComponentName(
            this@MainActivity,
            NewLauncherAlias::class.java,
        ),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP,
    )
    Toast.makeText(
        this@MainActivity,
        "Launcher one has been applied successfully",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    ).show()
}

fun updateToNewIcon(context: Activity) {
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        ComponentName(
            this@MainActivity,
            OldLauncherAlias::class.java,
        ),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP,
    )
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        ComponentName(
            this@MainActivity,
            NewLauncherAlias::class.java,
        ),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP,
    )

    Toast.makeText(
        this@MainActivity,
        "Launcher one has been applied successfully",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    ).show()
}
}
```

You can check complete demo project from [GitHub](https://github.com/rahul-hexalitics/DynamicLauncherIcon)

Comment: Rahul Mishra, Thanks for the answer. you are very cool! But I have a question: can this code be applied to webview? My application uses webview and if I create a menu in it using PHP and there is already a selection of the application icon, will changing the icon work or is another code needed?

Comment: If you want to change App icon from PHP code from WebView then You need to implement JavaScript interface with the WebView and then you have to manage the parameter receive from JavaScript Interface into your Android Source. You can refer this link https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview#UsingJavaScript for how to implement JavaScript Interface